# code coverage inside If block

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have the below code block in a batch method to send outbound MQ messages to the iSeries, which triggers an update of the record when the response is received.

```
try
{
    cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.OmgUpdate = false;
    OutboundMessageQueue__c dumbyId = [select id from OutboundMessageQueue__c limit 1];
    cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.Entity_Outbound(dumbyId.Id,c.id);

    string outMQFailureCode='';
    string outMQFailureReason='';

    if(cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.isSuccessfull == true){
        OutboundMessageQueue__c omq = new OutboundMessageQueue__c();
        omq.Message_Id__c = 'SPCIFA_BATCH';
        omq.MapId__c = '900';
        omq.sfObject__c = 'cif_Entity__c';
        omq.SFID__c = c.Id;
        omq.RequestType__c = 'CIF Equation Sync: ';
        omq.Description__c = 'Sync '+c.Name+' ('+c.ID_CIF__c+') with Equation'; 
        omq.Delivery_Failure_Code__c = cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.FailureCode;
        omq.Delivery_Failure_Reason__c = cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.FailureReason;

        outMQFailureCode = string.valueOf(omq.Delivery_Failure_Code__c);
        outMQFailureReason = omq.Delivery_Failure_Reason__c;

        insert omq;
        system.debug('MQ Msg created and inserted for: ' + c.Name);
    }

    updatedEntities += string.valueOf(c.Id)+','+ string.valueOf(c.Name)+',' +  string.valueOf(c.ID_CIF__c)+',' + myDatetimeStr + ',' + outMQFailureCode + ',' + outMQFailureReason + '\n';

    RecordNo++;        
    system.debug('EntityId: '+c.id);        
}
catch (exception ex){ ...
```

The batch runs fine, and does what it's supposed to, but I am having trouble getting code coverage of the section within the `If(cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.isSuccessfull == true){ ..}`

Here is my test method:

```
@isTest //(SeeAllData=true)
public class Batch_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status_TESTMETHOD{

    public static testmethod void testBatch_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status(){

        Service_Point_Setting__c sps = new Service_Point_Setting__c();
        sps.name = 'Migration';
        sps.value__c = 'false';
        insert sps;

        List <cif_Entity__c> listEntities = new List<cif_Entity__c>();

        cif_Entity__c ent = new cif_entity__c();
        ent.Salutation__c = 'Mrs';
        ent.Firstname__c    = 'Yellow';
        ent.Lastname__c = 'Sky';        
        ent.Equation_Status__c='Updating Equation';
        insert ent;
        listEntities.add(ent);

        test.startTest();
        string outMQFailureCode='';
        string outMQFailureReason='';

        cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.isSuccessfull=true;

        OutboundMessageQueue__c omq = new OutboundMessageQueue__c();
        omq.Message_Id__c = 'TEST_BATCH';
        omq.MapId__c = '900';
        omq.sfObject__c = 'cif_Entity__c';
        omq.SFID__c = ent.Id;
        omq.RequestType__c = 'Test Insert Message: ';
        omq.Description__c = 'TEST'; 
        omq.Delivery_Failure_Code__c = cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.FailureCode;
        omq.Delivery_Failure_Reason__c = cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.FailureReason;

        outMQFailureCode = string.valueOf(omq.Delivery_Failure_Code__c);
        outMQFailureReason = omq.Delivery_Failure_Reason__c;

        insert omq;

        BATCH_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status myClass = new BATCH_Ent_Update_Eqn_Status();
        myClass.lnumber = '1';
        database.executebatch(myClass,1);

        system.assertEquals(ent.Equation_Status__c='Equation Updated', ent.Equation_Status__c);
        system.debug('entity: ' + ' ' + ent.ID_CIF__c + '; ' + ent.Firstname__c + ', ' + ent.Lastname__c + ', Eqn Status: ' + ent.Equation_Status__c);
        /*
        for (cif_entity__c ent: listEntities){
            system.assertEquals(ent.Equation_Status__c='Equation Updated', ent.Equation_Status__c);
            system.debug('entity: ' + ' ' + ent.ID_CIF__c + '; ' + ent.Firstname__c + ', ' + ent.Lastname__c + ', Eqn Status: ' + ent.Equation_Status__c);
        }*/
        test.stopTest();                
    }
}
```

so as you an see, I have tried setting `cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.isSuccessfull=true;` in order to get that block to run, but no, here is what my code coverage looks like:

[image]

so what is the correct way to get that block of code to run?

We are trying to not use `SeeAllData=true` as we want the test methods to work automatically in every Org we deploy it to...

Comment: Correct way is try to avoid exception thrown inside Entity_Outbound method at line 56. Cn not say more from what code/screenshots

Comment: @kurunve:  yes you are correct in that, so in order to ensure there is an available id in the `OutboundMessageQueue__c` object I am inserting one record before starting the batch

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line:

```
cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.Entity_Outbound(dumbyId.Id,c.id);
```

Something goes terribly wrong there and it throws an exception which is then caught by your `catch` block and handled. That's also why your `catch` block is covered and the rest of `try` is red. I'd recomment debugging `cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.Entity_Outbound()` method to find what goes wrong and why does it throw an exception

Answer (score 2):

Add the commented  line into the apex code below

```
cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.OmgUpdate = false;
OutboundMessageQueue__c dumbyId = [select id from OutboundMessageQueue__c limit 1];
cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.Entity_Outbound(dumbyId.Id,c.id);
String outMQFailureCode = '';
String outMQFailureReason = '';

// Add this line 
if(isRunningTest()) {
    cif_Equation_Integration_Outbound_v1.isSuccessfull = true;
}
```

Comment: ram r -- you really ought to format your code before posting as an answer

Comment: Ok  will format code going ahead - thanks @cropredy